# Is possible to quickly select code and put into ie try block (VS 2010)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, try-catch

Suppose, I have very large foreach loop. I want put this loop into try catch block, but I do not want select by SHIFT + Arrow and cut, paste...

Comment: I've never found selecting code of any length to be a problem...

Comment: Of course the question is if it's a good idea to have such a large for each loop in the first place ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the code block you wish to surround with the try block, and press CTRL K+S (or right click, "Surround with") and type or select "try".

Comment: If it helped you, consider accepting it as answer (the checkmark at the left)

Answer (score 1):

Add `try {` where you want the block to begin. As soon as you add the closing `}` at the end, VS will automatically re-indent the contents of the `try` block. I'm not sure it gets any easier than that.

Comment: PS - this is the only solution that wouldn't require you to select the code.